# Extract array items as a view - AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to select all elements from an array that exists in one of the fields in Athena, for example:

```
{
    id: "1",
    name: "bla",
    array: [{
        val1: "2",
        val2: "2"
    }, {
        val1: "3",
        val2: "4"
    }]
}


{
    id: "3",
    name: "bla bla",
    array: [{
        val1: "5",
        val2: "6"
    }, {
        val1: "7",
        val2: "8"
    }]
}
```

I am trying to create a view that selects all the elements from the inner array, the result would be:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | val1 | val2 |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | 2    | 2    |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | 3    | 4    |
+----+------+------+
| 2  | 5    | 6    |
+----+------+------+
| 2  | 7    | 8    |
+----+------+------+
```

What is the query to produce such an output?

The actual file will be one item per line, like this:

{
    id: "1",
    name: "bla",
    array: [{
        val1: "2",
        val2: "2"
    }, {
        val1: "3",
        val2: "4"
    }]
}

{
    id: "3",
    name: "bla bla",
    array: [{
        val1: "5",
        val2: "6"
    }, {
        val1: "7",
        val2: "8"
    }]
}

The DDL to create the table looks like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE all (
  id STRING,
  name STRING,
  array ARRAY<
              struct<
               val1:STRING,
               val2:STRING
           >    >          
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://abc/def'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the expected result by following below steps:

1. Corrected JSON records from

```
{ id: "1", name: "bla", array: [{ val1: "2", val2: "2" }, { val1: "3", val2: "4" }] }
```

TO

```json
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "bla",
  "array": [
    {
      "val1": "2",
      "val2": "2"
    },
    {
      "val1": "3",
      "val2": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Created a table in Athena with below definition:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testt_json2( `id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', `name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', `array` array<struct<val1:string,val2:string>> COMMENT 'from deserializer') 
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('paths'='array,id,name') 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' 
    LOCATION 's3://test/'
```

3. Then ran a query with unnest to flatten the array which gave me expected result
   [image: screenshot of result]

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM testt_json2
)
SELECT id,
    t.names.val1,
    t.names.val2
FROM dataset
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(array) AS t(names)
```